# I want to use clamscan in node.js. Can anyone please suggest the steps if knows

Tags: node.js, clamav

Trying to install clamscan using docker file, here is my docker snippet

```
#Define the image we want to build from
FROM node:16.19.1-alpine3.17

#Copy the current directory to a newly created working directory
COPY --chown=1000 . /code

#Define the working directory - Change this to the directory your Node app is defined in
WORKDIR /code/server

RUN apk update && apk upgrade

RUN npm install --quiet node-gyp -g

# Run image as root user
USER root

RUN apk --no-cache add clamav clamav-daemon freshclam clamav-libunrar supervisor

RUN sed -i 's/^Foreground .*$/Foreground true/g' /etc/clamav/clamd.conf && \
    echo 'TCPSocket 3310' >> /etc/clamav/clamd.conf && \
    sed -i 's/^Foreground .*$/Foreground true/g' /etc/clamav/freshclam.conf

RUN freshclam

RUN mkdir /run/clamav && chown clamav:clamav /run/clamav

EXPOSE 3310/tcp

# Run image as non-root user
USER node

RUN npm rebuild

#This app binds to the below specified port, so we use the EXPOSE instruction to have it mapped by the docker daemon
EXPOSE 11012

# Run image as non-root user
USER node

# Run application
CMD [ "node", "server.js"]
```

when i started to using the clamscan.isInfected(localFullPath) nodejs application it throws the below error,

```
/usr/bin/clamdscan --no-summary --fdpass --multiscan /code/server/attachments/image.jpeg
```

Comment: hi, what is this line? `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`  If not important, you can delete or fix that...

Comment: @pierpy can you please look it now

Comment: That's a command line, not an error.

Comment: @GopalakrishnanM maybe you don't know what is Docker? Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software))